# how to access to a public mapping from test script

Tags: solidity, hardhat, mapping, public-key

i'm in hardhat
i'v this public mapping

```
    mapping (address user => uint[] commentIds) public userComments;
```

and i'm trying to call it inside my **test Script**

```js
        console.log(`user1 comments:  ${await postContract.userComments(user1.address)}`);
```

i get this error      Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8" ], "key": "userComments" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.8.0)

**i can access to the mapping by create a getter function but why is that isn't that public modifier  already do that under the hood **